# How to bind child element attributes to fields with JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Given the following XML

```
<mappings>
  <map>
     <source srcAttr="oof">foo</source>
     <target trgAttr="rab">bar</target>
  </map>
  <map>
    ...
```

Is it possible with JAXB to unmarshal the `<map>` elements into a single class `Map` 
containing values *and* attributes of `<source>` and `<target>`?

```
@XmlRootElement
class Map {

   @XmlElement
   String source;

   @???
   String srcAttr;

   @XmlElement
   String target;

   @???
   String trgAttr;
}
```

I don't want to create extra classes for Source and target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! Just replace `???` with `@XmlAttribute` annotaion.

Also this might be helpful [jaxb example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/) and this [oracle examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/examples.html)

Comment: That will put the XML attributes into the `map` element instead of the `source` and `target` elements.  FYI - Here is how you could handle this use case using MOXy's `@XmlPath` extension:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17424618/383861

Comment: put the XML attributes into the map element instead of the source and target elements -- looks like that's what Udo wants

Comment: Since I'm interested only into unmarshalling, this is exactly what I want! Didn't thought it would be that easy :-)

Comment: But that is the Attribute is not at source or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [JAXB (JSR-222)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

You could use MOXy's `@XmlPath` extension to handle this use case:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Map {

   String source;

   @XmlPath("source/@srcAttr")
   String srcAttr;

   String target;

   @XmlPath("target/@trgAttr")
   String trgAttr;

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html

Comment: This is real luxury ;-)
Unfortunately I have to stick with the javee standard